# Radial Gradient Clippath

Tags: svg, gradient, clip-path

I'm wanting to use a clip path to expose an image behind another image.

Im using an svg circle element. The result I want is for a soft, gradient edge, instead of a hard edge supplied by the clipPath.

Is this possible? I know that I can do it with a mask, but cant seem to get it to work with clipPath.

Heres my code so far:

```
 <svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 500 500">
              <defs>

                    <radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
                      <stop stop-color="white" offset="0%"/>
                      <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%"/>
                    </radialGradient>
                    <clipPath id="clip1" >
                        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="url(#grad)"  />
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>


              <image id="darkMap"  xlink:href="images/darkMapSml.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
             <image id="topImg" xlink:href="images/lightMapSml.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip1)" />


         </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use a `<mask>` if you want gradients, `<clipPath>` only considers the geometry of the shapes inside.

Comment: Thank you Erik...A further question. If i go the mask route...which ive tried...and add multiple circle svg's to the mask dynmically(onclick), it starts to slow down performance and becomes laggy when scrolling around image. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: I'd suggest asking that as a new question, with more complete code, and include details for when you experience the lagging (what device, browser etc).

Comment: lol...i have, but no one wants to answer it...haha, but thanks for your help anyways :)